# How can I make a music playlist out of a .txt file?

Tags: bash, music, command-line

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 (I don't think that really matters) with Bash.

How can I make a music playlist out of a `.txt` file? It is a command but I forgot it. I would appreciate it if someone would write a tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to go to the folder of the music, than type:

```
ls > music.txt
```

The `.txt` file can be named what ever you want. The `ls` uses all the files in the folder, listing them and the `>` **redirects** the command to a `.txt`. Than press **Enter** or **Return** and that's it. If you are using **mplayer** for example, you type

```
mplayer -playlist music.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many [playlist formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Playlist_file_formats).

[M3U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#File_format) is a simple plain text file format for playlists.  Where each line is a location (this can be a relative path, an absolute path or a URL). Example (a_playlist.m3u):

```
./cat_dna.mp3
/foo/bar/Eternal Wheel.flac
http://example.com/sploosh.ogg
```

With mplayer I could play the above like so:

```
mplayer -playlist /path/to/a_playlist.m3u
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/music -type f -iname "*.ogg" > myplaylist.txt
```

for other extension just change `*.ogg`
example for mp3 `*.ogg` to `*.mp3`